# Calling static method from another java class

Tags: java

I've recently switched from working in PHP to Java and have a query.  Want to emphasise I'm a beginner in Java.

Essentially I am working in File A (with class A) and want to refer to a static method saved in File B (class B).  Do I need to make any reference to File B when working with class A?  (I'm thinking along the lines of require_once in PHP) My code in Class A is as follows:

```
Public class A{
String[] lists = B.staticMethod();
}
```

Eclipse is not recognising B as a class. Do I need to create an instance of B in order to access the static method.  Feel like I'm really overlooking something and would appreciate any input.

Comment: Are those classes in different packages? If yes then you need to import `B` class in `A` class.

Comment: static methods do not require an instance. Everything looks fine, however the `public` keyword should start with a lowercase 'p'. If `B` is in another package, you need to add an import statement: `import package_of_B.B;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ensure you have proper access to B.staticMethod. Perhaps declare it as

```
public static String[] staticMethod() {
    //code
}
```

Also, you need to import class B

```
import foo.bar.B; // use fully qualified path foo.bar.B

public class A {
    String[] lists = B.staticMethod();
}
```

Comment: hello, can I know the reason why we have to use `static` if we want to call the method from one class to another class

Comment: Why can't we have something like `import foo.bar.B.staticMethod;` and then directly use it as `String[] lists = staticMethod();` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create an instance of the class to call a static method, but you do need to import the class.

```
package foo;

//assuming B is in same package
import foo.B;

Public class A{
  String[] lists = B.staticMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has classloader mechanism that is kind of similar to PHP's autoloader. This means that you don't need anything like a `include` or `require` function: as long as the classes that you use are on the "classpath" they will be found.

Some people will say that you have to use the [`import` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html). That's not true; `import` does nothing but give you a way to refer to classes with their short names, so that you don't have to repeat the package name every time.

For example, code in a program that works with the `ArrayList` and `Date` classes could be written like this:

```
java.util.ArrayList<java.util.Date> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
list.add(new java.util.Date());
```

Repeating the package name gets tiring after a while so we can use `import` to tell the compiler we want to refer to these classes by their short name:

```
import java.util.*;
....
ArrayList<Date> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also import the static method only, like this:

```
import static packageX.packageY.B.staticMethod;
```

Then call the method directly from inside your class method A without using a class name, like this:

```
String[] lists = staticMethod();
```