# How to pass a method as an argument to a different method?

Tags: java, method-reference

I have a method let's say in `ClassA`. I want to pass a method from `ClassB` as an argument to that method in `ClassA`. In this case I want to pass the `getCode` method from `ClassB`. I don't have any instance of `ClassB` and I'd like to achieve this without having to create one.

I've tried using simple method reference, but it does not work this way.
I don't want to make getCode a static method either.

```
public class ClassA {

   public void validate() {
       Validation validation = new Validation(ClassB::getCode, code);
       //...
   }

}
```

My final goal is to have a RequestValidator class to which add validations, each validation will be created with a specific method and a string in its constructor, in this case getCode from classB and code. Please note I only want one instance of RequestValidator. Something like this:

```
RequestValidator validator = new RequestValidator<>()
        .addValidation(new Validation(ClassB::getCode, code))
        .addValidation(new Validation(ClassB::getName, name));
```

Comment: You want to pass `ClassB::getCode` to `Validation` which took `ClassA::getCode`?

Comment: You can only do this if the constructor of `Validation` accepts a `Function<ClassB, WhateverTypeGetCodeReturns>`. Does it?

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah that did the trick thank you.

Answer (score 0):

getCode needs to be a static function, and the syntax would be ClassB.getCode. You would need ClassB to be imported into ClassA.

See:

[Calling static method from another java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834005/calling-static-method-from-another-java-class)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a method reference will work just fine as long as you define the method arguments properly.  You haven't given a lot of information, so I'm going to make some assumptions here.  Please correct me if this isn't what you had in mind:

```
public class B { 
  public static String getCode() {
    return "foobar"; // Replace with your own functionality
  }
}

public class Validation {
  Validation(Supplier<String> supplier, String code) {
    String suppliedCode = supplier.get();
    // Do your validation logic
  }
}

public static void validate() {
  Validation validation = new Validation(ClassB::getCode, code);
}
```

But this frankly feels like overkill.  Why can't you just make your `Validation` constructor take two String arguments (or whatever types you happen to be using), and then do this?

```
public static void validate() {
  Validation validation = new Validation(ClassB.getCode(), code);
}
```

Do you have a legitimate need to pass in a method reference instead of simply passing in the return value from the method call?

Comment: Yeah I'll explain a bit more, I have a RequestValidator class and what I want is to add validations to that class, each validation will be created with a specific method and a string, in this case getCode from classB and code. Please note I only want one instance of RequestValidator. Something like this:

```RequestValidator validator = new RequestValidator<>()
  .addValidation(new Validation(ClassB::getCode, code))
  .addValidation(new Validation(ClassB::getName, name));```