# How to get resoult of function from another class that is called from yet another class with values

Tags: java, dictionary, pass-by-reference

It is basic, but I am really new in Java...
In `Controller.class` I get the values(centers, dataset, k) with which I start my "boss method"

```
 Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k);
```

this method calls many linked methods in `Main.class`. One of the methods I need is pobarvajClusterje:

```
public static Map<String, TockaXY> pobarvajClusterje(List<TockaXY> kmeans, int k) {

    List<String> barve = new ArrayList<>();
    barve.add("Modra");
    barve.add("Rumena");
    barve.add("Zelena");
    barve.add("Rdeca");
    barve.add("Vijola");
    barve.add("Crna");
    barve.add("Oranzna");
    barve.add("Roza");
    barve.add("Rjava");
    barve.add("Siva");

    Map<String, TockaXY> barvniCluster = new IdentityHashMap<>(k);

    for (int d = 0; d < k; d++) {
        barvniCluster.put(barve.get(d), kmeans.get(d));
    }
    return barvniCluster;
}
```

This method does return a

```
Map<String, TockaXY> barvniCluster = new IdentityHashMap<>(k);
```

So how to get this Map in a third `WebView.class` to iterate over it? 
Because I have to call the function from `WebView.class` in `Main.class` with parameters from `Control.class`.
Or am I declaring functions in wrong way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling static method from another java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834005/calling-static-method-from-another-java-class)

Comment: Thanks for link, it clears a little bit, but I still don't get how to actually implement... I have to call the function from WebView.class in Main.class with parameters from Control.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call the public static method from `Main.class`, you'd write something like following in the `Control.java`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, TockaXY> output = Main.pobarvajClusterje(argument1, argument2);
}
```

Depending upon the arrangement of your packages, you might have to import `Main` in your current class in order to call this method as I've mentioned.

The `main` method is just for example, you can of course call from inside any method in `Control` class.

Comment: Like this Eclipse is happy: Map<String, TockaXY> output = Main.pobarvajClusterje(Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k), k);   Like this i got the values in method, but now i have to get it in WebView class to iterate the result. Because I can't get it with SampleController.output;

Comment: That is so because `output` is not a static variable in your `SampleController`. You can do something like `public static Map<String, TockaXY> output` and use this `output` variable to assign and reuse the values from the method output. 
But, for a clearer understanding of Java language constructs, I highly recommend reading a good book before jumping into complex TODOs.